# How to use OpenMapTiles hosted on my server into android kotlin

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, mapbox, openmaptiles

I have hosted OpenMapTiles on my own server. but I don't know how to use it in my android app using Mapbox SDK or any other GL SDK. Is there any way to use OpenMapTiles in android and if any please let me know.

Thanks in adavance!